# laravel в коллекцию добавить коллекцию

Tags: php, массивы, laravel, коллекции

Есть массив

```
$data['sites'] = Site::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
```

исходя из него формирую дополнительный массив

```
foreach($data['sites'] as $key=>$site){
            $data['sites'][$key]['prices'] = Price::where('site_id', $site['id'])
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
        }
```

И получаю удобный для себя массив, только вот уже нужна коллекция, чтобы формировать связи. Подкажите как правильно сделать, пробовал через мерж - не получилось.

Comment: `$data['sites']->{$key}->prices = ....` так пробовали?

Comment: Property [0] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @Arendach пробовал комбинировать по разному, не получается :С

Comment: Блин, ну и реализация. Ссори за прямоту, но это говнокод. Во-первых, конвертировать в массив  не обязательно - модель использует `ArrayAccess`. Во-вторых - создай релейшн к модели `Price` и используй т н. Eager loading (жадная загрузка) и тогда твой код сократится до одной строки `Site::with('prices')->get()`. Почитай раздел доков eloquent

Comment: @МаксимК Конвертировал я в массив для своих нужд, далее там идёт много условий в выборке что в sites что в price. Так вот вернемся к вопросу как соеденить две коллекции в одну? Site::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get() и Price::where('site_id', $site['id'])
            ->get()

Comment: Тогда сделай релейшн в модели Site к модели Price (hasMany) и сделай так, как я описал в предыдущем комментарии и у тебя будет то, о чем ты спрашивал